# Batch remove specific info from filename in 3K .pdf files while preserving remaining info?

Tags: finder, applescript, pdf, script, macos

I have about 3K .pdf documents named to the following filename convention:

`BER_0020236-BER_0020293.pdf`

the next file in the sequence could be something like

`BER_4039464-BER_9384762.pdf` (the numbers are nonsequential).

What I need to do is preserve the first part of the filename `BER_0020236`, while removing the rest and preserving extension `.pdf`.

I thought I could use "rename" from the right-click options, select replace, and then input `-*******` with a `blank` replacement. This doesn't work - perhaps because finder isn't recognizing * as a wildcard? I can remove `-` easily, but not characters after `-`.

Is there an extant script somewhere that would do this, or is there something I'm missing from the finder option?

Comment: I should say in the meantime I found https://manytricks.com/namemangler/ which accomplished nicely - however, I'm still looking for an answer here if possible.

Comment: I wrote a python script to do something similar a while ago. It was a pretty easy build, but I don’t know where I saved it... (rather, I think I saved it on my desktop which is currently being transported cross-country)

Comment: Sorry to ask this, but can you please mark the question as answered? I want to put a bounty on a question I have and need the points. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick (just edit FolderTemp to something that works):

```
tell application "Finder"
    set FolderTemp to alias "Folder with all files"
    set allfiles to files of FolderTemp
    repeat with i from 1 to count of allfiles
        set CurrentFile to item i of allfiles
        set filename to name of item i of allfiles
        set x to offset of "-" in filename
        set y to offset of "." in filename
        set NewFileName to characters 1 thru (x - 1) of filename as string
        set Extension to characters y thru -1 of filename as string
        set NewFileName to NewFileName & Extension as string
        set name of CurrentFile to NewFileName
    end repeat
end tell
```

I hope it helps.